# Congrats to the newly-elected mods!

Tags: discussion, election-2012

voretaq7, Chris S, and Iain -

Congratulations, gentlemen. All of you are model SE citizens, and I couldn't think of a better bunch to get diamonds this year.

I think I speak for all SF users when I say "thank you" for the vast amount work you've already done on the site as well as for that which you will take on in your new moderator roles.

Congrats!

(now, don't you have some flags to attend to or something?) :)

Comment: What's a flag? ::hides::

Comment: Hey - you look pretty good in a diamond. :)

Comment: Voretaq7 as a model citizen?  I've seen it all!

Comment: Diamonds are a mod's best friends.

Comment: Hear hear - well done yous guys

Comment: Which one of you didn't act on this, when I flagged it as "Not a Question" :D

Comment: @MDMarra - I was wondering how long it would be before someone flagged this. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now get to work​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​, I hear that WesleyDavid comes online in the next hour or so

Comment: The barometric pressure in the flag queue is dropping.  *A storm is coming.*

Comment: Nothing like seeing 56 flags in the queue to make you wish you had help.

Comment: What about vgv8?

Answer (score 5):

I'd just like to repeat what I've said elsewhere - Deciding who to vote for was anything but easy. I just wish we had candidates even 1% as worthy and honourable during political elections.

Comment: Yep - I actually spent more time debating this before voting than I did in the last political elections I voted in.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed! The best of luck to you all! Go get em!

(Is that what they are supposed to do?)

Answer (score 2):

[image: I voted for Kodos]

My fellow ServerFaultians. As a young boy, I dreamed of being a baseball, but
tonight I say, we must move forward, not backward, upward not forward,
and always twirling, twirling, twirling towards ponypictures.SE

Answer (score 1):

Well done gents, welcome! Now maybe I won't wake up to Wesleys special delivery of flags!

Answer (score 1):

Good luck and may our chat room be filled with even more blues!

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations and welcome! Also, thanks to all the other candidates who would have deserved it too!

[image: congratulate]